# Max number of edges in a directed graph?

Tags: directed-graph

I am a bit confused about max number of edges in a directed  graph with N nodes.

Various sources say its N*(N-1), argument being that from every node we can connect to other (N-1) remaining nodes, and hence total max number of edges

> N * (N-1)

But in a directed graph we are allowed to move in only one direction between a pair of nodes. So if first node has N-1 options to move to, then second one would have one less, and so on.

What am I missing here?

Comment: directed is not equal acyclic

Answer (score 0):

There is an implied but unstated assumption about the sets of edges that are allowed.

Two nodes, A and B, might be connected by no edge, or an edge from A to B, or an edge from B to A. If those are the only possibilities, then the greatest possible number of edges is N(N-1)/2.

If it is also permitted to have an edge from A to B *and* an edge from B to A, then the greatest possible number of edges is N(N-1).

Comment: But then it is not a directed graph if A -> B and B -> A are both allowed, isn't?

Comment: @Mandroid - it's those little arrows that makes it directed

Comment: @Mandroid: That's just it; there are different conventions in use. Some sources say that that is a directed graph, some say that it isn't, some say that it isn't a graph at all.